# Satisfy Typescript defining a type that can be either Timestamp (from Firebase/Firestore) or Date

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a small learning project I am building with React + Typescript, I am storing some messages in Firestore, and rendering them afterwards.
One of the fields is a date, that in firestore I defined as `date = timestamp`
When I create the message in my component, y create it as `date = new Date()`

Since I defined `date: Timestamp | Date` , if I render the messages as `{msg.date.seconds}` , given that `Type Date` do not share the same properties as `Timestamp`, typescript complains.

My way of solving it is as I show in `formDate()` function.

But I am not sure that is a good solution. I'd prefer `formatDate()` typed like this : `const formatDate = (seconds:number):string {}` . But I cannot find a good way to satisfy TS with that definition.

Is there a cleaner, or better way to type it?

I edit my comment to clarify my doubt.
Initially, I typed `date: Timestamp`,and I was rendering my p tag as `<p> {formatDate(msg.date.seconds)}</p>` since property date is an object of shape `{nanoseconds: number , seconds: number}`

But the moment I define the `newMessage` object, and i generate `date: new Date()`, I "have to" now type the field date as an union `date:TimeStamp | Date` , but in then TS complains since the property `seconds` is not missing in type `Date`.
Hope this clarifies it.

My code is

```
interface MessagesType {
  text: string;
  date: Timestamp | Date;
}

function Messages() {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessagesType[] | null>(
    null
  );
  const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState("");

  const getMessages = async () => {
    //...getting messages from Firebase
    });
    setMessages(messagesArray);
  };

//Function to format the input date, and to satisfy TS
  const formatDate = (date: Timestamp | Date): string => {
    if (date instanceof Timestamp) {
      // If it's a Timestamp, access the seconds property
      return new Date(date.seconds * 1000).toLocaleString();
    } else {
      // If it's a Date, no need to multiply by 1000
      return date.toLocaleString();
    }
  };

  const addNewMessage = async (): Promise<void> => 
    const newMessage: MessagesType = {
      text: messageText,
      date: new Date(),
    };
    // Add a new message
  };


  useEffect(() => 
    getMessages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Messages</h1>
      
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setMessageText(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <Button onClick={sendMessage}></Button>
        </div>
        {messages &&
          messages.map((msg) => {
            console.log("msg :>> ", msg);
            return (
              <div>
                <p>{msg.text}</p>
                <p>{formatDate(msg.date)}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Messages;
```

Here below I add the code that it is not passing the type check :

```
interface MessagesType {
  text: string;
  date: Timestamp | Date;
}

function Messages() {

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessagesType[] | null>(
    null
  );
  const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState("");

  const getMessages = async () => {
    //code to get messages from Firestore
    });
    setMessages(messagesArray);
  };


  const formatDate = (seconds:number): string => {
      return new Date(seconds * 1000).toLocaleString();
  };

  const addNewMessage = async (): Promise<void> => 
    const newMessage: MessagesType = {
      text: messageText,
      date: new Date(),
    };
    // code to Add a new message to Firestore
  };


  useEffect(() => 
    getMessages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Messages</h1>
      
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setMessageText(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <Button onClick={sendMessage}></Button>
        </div>
        {messages &&
          messages.map((msg) => {
            console.log("msg :>> ", msg);
            return (
              <div>
                <p>{msg.text}</p>
    {/*TS error:  Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Timestamp | Date' */}
                <p>{formatDate(msg.date.seconds)}</p>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Messages;
```

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable. Unclear what you're asking with `(date:number):string` - that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: An alternative is "discriminated unions" (Google it) but I probably wouldn't bother in this instance.

Comment: When I get the messages from Firebase,the field date is an object as `date: { nanoseconds:123456, seconds:78902}` 
Therefore, to format the date, i was doing `<p> {formatDate(msg.date.seconds)}</p>}` 
But the moment the property date I type it as an union `Timestamp | Date` , TS complains since `Date`do not contain `seconds` .
I don't know if that clarifies it

Comment: How adding a message to firebase looks like? One solution is to have two types: one with `Date` for adding new objects to firebase, another one with `Timestamp` for objects retrieved from firebase. But you didn't show how you are adding to firebase, so I can't tell if this will work

Comment: I add messages to firebase with the function `const addNewMessage` , you can find it in my code.  , i create this object 
` const newMessage: MessagesType = {
      text: messageText,
      date: new Date(),
    };`

Comment: If I got the problem correctly... You cannot validate the seconds like this: `if ("seconds" in date && date?.seconds) {` instead of `if (date instanceof Timestamp) {`?

Comment: @Zero not exactly. My problem is that, if I type `date: Timestamp | Date` , and `const formatDate = (date:number):string ` (which is in reality what this function should do, receive a number of seconds, and transform them into a date string) , i cannot do `<p>{formatDate(msg.date?.seconds)}</p>` , since TS rightfully complains that `Property 'seconds' does not exist on type 'Timestamp | Date'`

Comment: Typescript has flow typing based on `instanceof`, which is why it knows that `date` is a `Date` on this line: `// If it's a Date, no need to multiply by 1000`.  I'm still not clear what you're actually asking for...

Comment: @Timmmm , what I am asking is , if there is a way to satisfy Typescript (in a good way, ofc) with what I said before: Having the property  ` date: Timestamp | Date` , and the function `formatDate = (date:number):string`  , to be able to pass an argument like this ` <p>{formatDate(msg.date?.seconds)}</p> ` . 
Why I would I like to do that? because from Firebase, the field Date will always arrive as a Timestamp

Comment: If the `date` field always arrives as a Timestamp then just type it as `Timestamp`. But from your code it looks like you can add `Date`s too so it's not really relevant what Firebase returns.

Comment: Maybe you should post the code that doesn't type check and we can explain why.

Comment: @Timmmm , thanks for the suggestion. Done, inserted right below.

Comment: Ah I think I see the confusion. When you send a message to Firebase you can send a `Date` or a `Timestamp` and when you receive one it's always a `Timestamp`, is that correct?

Comment: @Timmmm exactly!

Comment: The simplest solution would be to change the type to be only `Timestamp` and just have `addNewMessage()` convert the `Date` to a `Timestamp`.

Comment: you mean to manually transform a `new Date()`value  into an object ` = {seconds:1234, nanoseconds:4590890}` ?